# Cannot boot Win7 after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure

I know this comes up quite a bit, but none of the other questions have helped me.  I have tried using Boot Repair, but didn't have any luck.

This is what it comes up with: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1204105/

I have 3 hard drives - 1 60GB with Windows 7, 1 300GB with games, programs, and music, and 1 320GB that I decided to install Ubuntu on.  I thought I did everything correctly, but Windows 7 doesn't come up as an option in Grub, nor can I boot to the Windows drive anymore.  It hangs at the loading screen.  I have also tried the bootrec.exe/fixmbr and fixboot trick as well, and while they said they were successful I still cannot boot to the drive.  I have not touched the Windows 7 partitions.

Unfortunately there are a few files I have on the Windows partition that I'd like to recover if possible, but the drive doesn't show up for me at all.  This is my first real run with Linux, although I have used bootable CDs before, so I think it's safe to say that I don't know what I'm doing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mount the Windows partitions on Nautilus and back up your files, they should appear in the sidebar of Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair indicates in its final screen:

```
The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

So:

1. Boot your Ubuntu liveCD, choose `Try Ubuntu`
2. Run [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) to reduce the size of your Ubuntu partition (`sdc2`) from 318GB to `100GB`. (reduce it `from the right-side`, so that it still begins at the start of the disk).
3. Reboot the PC `without the liveCD`, it should display the GRUB menu with Windows/Ubuntu choice. (if any problem, run Boot-Repair again and tell the new URL that will appear)